# Convert decimal fractions to binary using sum of power of 2 method

Tags: numbers, system

**How to convert the following decimal fractions to binary?**

```
1/2=0.1 

1/4= 0.01
1/8=0.001
```

> How can these be assigned??
>
> Please explain...

Comment: Explain what? What is your question exactly?

Comment: Mr. Shree How did get 0.1 for 1/2  and 1/4 for 0.01

Comment: http://cs.furman.edu/digitaldomain/more/ch6/dec_frac_to_bin.htm

Answer (score 0):

In the decimal numeration, the digits have the following weights:

```
... 10000 1000 100 10 1 comma 1/10 1/100 1/1000 1/10000 ...
```

so that

23.51d is 2 x 10 + 3 x 1  + 5 x 0.1 + 1 x 0.01

Similarly, in the binary numeration, the weights are

```
... 16 8 4 2 1 comma 1/2 1/4 1/8 1/16 ...
```

so that

11.01b is 1 x 2 + 1 x 1 + 0 x 1/2 + 1 x 1/4 = 3.25d

And

0.1b is 1/2

0.01b is 1/4

0.001b is 1/8

...

Comment: 0.5= 1 * 2^-1=0.1  Explain this step only (1 * 2^1) how did come??

Comment: 0.5 decimal number = 1 X 2 power -1 = 0.1 binary how this possible.

Comment: Do you understand what is a weight ?

Comment: Read my answer again and again.